# How to keep the Spark web UI alive?

Tags: apache-spark

After the end of the execution of Spark submit, the Spark web UI is killed. Is there a way to keep it alive?

I am using Spark 1.2.1.

Answer (score 18):

To add a newbie friendly step-by-step solution of how to work with the history server:

- In the spark distribution folder try to start the history server by:

  `./sbin/start-history-server.sh`

  By default the history server will try to monitor `/tmp/spark-events` for logs and unfortunately it will crash if the path doesn't exist. So if you get an error you may have to `mkdir /tmp/spark-events` first. You can check the history server logs in `./logs` to see details in case of trouble.
- In order for a context to persists its event log, you have to enable event logging. This can be done either programmatically or by editing `./conf/spark-defaults.conf` (copy the template if it doesn't exist yet), and uncommenting/adding the line:

  `spark.eventLog.enabled           true`

  Running a `spark-submit` should result in event log folders like `/tmp/spark-events/local-1465133722470`.
- Access the history server UI, typically from http://localhost:18080

Comment: Make sure `/tmp/spark-events` have the right permissions

Answer (score 13):

If you are testing in local mode i.e. using IDEA or Eclipse, one way is to do is as following.

```
System.in.read();
spark.stop(); // spark --> SparkSession
```

This will ensure that the UI is accessible as long as you want. Just hit enter on the IDEA/Eclipse console to terminate the application

Answer (score 6):

You can use Spark's event logging and history server features to view the UIs of completed applications; see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The web UI is intrinsically tied to the `SparkContext`, so if you do not call `.stop` and keep your application alive, then the UI should remain alive. If you need to view the logs, then those should still be persisted to the server, though. It might make for an interesting feature to keep the web server portion open for a time period, or some other view, though, possibly a feature request?

From [SparkContext.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fspark%2FSparkContext.scala)

```
// Initialize the Spark UI
private[spark] val ui: Option[SparkUI] =
if (conf.getBoolean("spark.ui.enabled", true)) {
  Some(SparkUI.createLiveUI(this, conf, listenerBus, jobProgressListener,
    env.securityManager,appName))
} else {
  // For tests, do not enable the UI
  None
}


/** Shut down the SparkContext. */
  def stop() {
    SparkContext.SPARK_CONTEXT_CONSTRUCTOR_LOCK.synchronized {
      postApplicationEnd()
      ui.foreach(_.stop())
      ...
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE - BETTER ANSWER**

I had forgotten about the spark history server. [That is something you might want to look into](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

Comment: Yep. I do not know how to keep my application alive.

Comment: I updated about the spark history server, which I then noticed Josh Rosen answered, but it is more accurate than my original answer

Answer (score 0):

may be you can add the line :

`new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()`

make sure it run in driver

Answer (score 0):

While locally testing Spark applications written in Python, I add this as a little hack to the end of my apps:

```
raw_input("Press ctrl+c to exit")
```

When running on a YARN cluster manager, I use the history manager available on port 18080.

Comment: where should I write this ? raw_input("Press ctrl+c to exit") in pyspark code?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to your Answer**

1. Before SparkContext to stop, use Thread.sleep(86400000). This will keep 24 hours active of your Spark UI until you kill the process. This is not an **advisable** solution.

   ```
   SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]");
   JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
   Thread.sleep(86400000); //throws InterruptedException. 
   sc.stop();
   ```

   2. Best Solution is to log Spark events somewhere and use spark history server.

      ```
      spark.eventLog.enabled=true
      $ ./sbin/start-history-server.sh
      ```

Answer (score 0):

As Justin Pihony mentioned above, "The web UI is intrinsically tied to the SparkContext". It is alive as long as SparkContext is alive.

What we can try is to delay the calling of stop() on SparkContext object.
I've tried this and it works well for me:

```
//Perform your spark transformations and actions
  ..............................
//In the end
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
service.schedule(() -> sparkSession.stop(), 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
service.shutdown();
```

You can change the time according your need.